# google javascript place library - nearby search & getDetails result don't return photos object

Tags: javascript, google-places-api, google-places

I was trying to get local images for lat/lng with java-script.I have tried Google place java-script API for same.It is found that autocomplete.getPlace() return photos object in result but service.nearbySearch or service.getDetails don't return the same.
like

```
var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
console.log(place.photos) /*OK return photos object*/
```

But following code don't return photos object in result.

```
service.nearbySearch(request, callback);

function callback(results.status){
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {     
        var place=results[0];
        console.log(place.photos);/* undefined don't return photos */
    }
}
```

Or

```
service.getDetails(request, callback);

function callback(results.status){
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {     
        var place=results[0];
        console.log(place.photos);/* undefined undefined don't return photos */
    }
}
```

Can anybody help me to understand if it is a bug or is there any issue with my code.

Here is my [CodePen](http://codepen.io/babin78/pen/zNrLrj/) link

Answer (score 0):

From what I see you only pass the result status instead of the full result. Try this instead.

```
service.nearbySearch(request, callback);

function callback(results){
    if (results.status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {     
        var place=results[0];           
    }
}
```

If this doesn't work, you might need to call the getDetail service of that place, such as

```
function callback(results){
        if (results.status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {     
            var place=results[0];  
            service.getDetails(place, callback2);
        }
    }
```

Or course you will need a callback2 function. But for now test the first part, not sure the 2nd is necessary (been a while since I did this)

Comment: Sorry for typo mistake.please read  callback(results,status) instead of callback(results.status). Appreciate your revert for same.